# Python: call methods on default object

Tags: python

Is it possible to call methods on a default object? To explain what I mean, here's an example:

There's Foo.py with a class:

```
class Foo:
    def fooMethod():
        print "doSomething"

fooObject = Foo()
```

And another pythonscript Bar.py:

```
from Foo import *
// what I can do now is:
fooObject.fooMethod()
// what I need is that this:
fooMethod()
// is automatically executed on fooObject if the method was not found in Bar.py
```

Is there any possibility to make this work? What I need is to set a "default"-object on which methods are executed if the method was not found.

Answer (score 3):

This has been done in Python's `random` module.  They use a [simple and straight-forward solution](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d3a82a26c705/Lib/random.py#l875):

```
class Foo:
    def foo_method(self):
        print "do something"

foo_object = Foo()
foo_method = foo_object.foo_method
```

It would also be possible to write some introspection code to automatically propagate all methods of `Foo` to the module namespace, but I recommend against doing so.

Comment: I know this is possible. The problem I have is that foo_object can be changed to be different object with different methods in the one module, so I would have to write:

Comment: Sorry ignore first comment please ^^.. The problem I have is that foo_object can be changed to be a different object with different methods in the module I'm importing, so I would have to write an alias for every possible object-method that foo_object can have. I would'nt want to do that.

Comment: @kel: If `foo_object` changes, you want the module contents to magically change as well?  This sounds like a terrible idea.  Morover, what about other modules that did `from Foo import *` before?  They will have to reimport everything.  (Using `from Foo import *` in production code is generally a bad idea.)

Comment: What I was really looking for was the functionality of __getattr__ for classes or the setattr(module,name,attribute). I'm sorry, I think my question was not so clear. Thank you for your answer anyway =)